# JSON creation from Arraylist

Tags: java, json

I have to create JSON response like the below one.

```
    [{"Name":"Shampoo","Qty":"3","Amt":"300"},
    {"Name":"Soap","Qty":"1","Amt":"50"}]
```

### Code:

```
    ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();
    al.addAll(name);
    al.addAll(qty);
    al.addAll(price);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson( al );

    System.out.println(json);
    JSONObject pa = new JSONObject();
    childData = new JSONObject();

    try {
        childData.put("Name", name);
        childData.put("Qty", qty);
        childData.put("Amt", price);
        pa.put("Detais",childData);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the above code creates the response like this

```
      {"Name":"[Shampoo, Soap]","Qty":"[3, 1]","Amt":"[300, 50]"}
```

Comment: What do `name`, `qty` and `price` contain?

Comment: I dont get what is your question, is that json what you want or what you already have??

Comment: You haven't included enough code and you didn't ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `al.addAll()` calls I deduce `name`, `qty`, and `price` are lists. So you are handing lists to the `childData.put()` calls. This produces the output you found, and array of values at each JSON key (child element) containing all elements in the list handed to that `childData.put()` call.

If you want your first JSON you should loop over all elements in you list and add (put) them one by one on a parent element that resembles your (name, qty, price) pair. E.g.

```
JSONArray jA  = new JSONArray()
for(int j=0; j<condition;j++){
    JSONObject pa = new JSONObject();
    for(int i=0; i<name.length;i++) {
        childData = new JSONObject();
        childData.put("Name", name[i]);
        childData.put("Qty", qty[i]);
        childData.put("Amt", price[i]);
        pa.put("Detais",childData);
    }
    jA.put(pa);
}
```

Comment: childData= {"Name":"Shampoo","Qty":"2","Amt":"300"}
      pa= [{"Name":"Shampoo","Qty":"2","Amt":"300"}]
      childData= {"Name":"Soap","Qty":"3","Amt":"210"}
      pa= [{"Name":"Soap","Qty":"3","Amt":"210"},    {"Name":"Soap","Qty":"3","Amt":"210"}].     In pa JSONArray last childData value is getting stored

Comment: Well you have to loop creation of parents as well in an outer loop of course and add to an json array.